# how to convert MException into one line string

Tags: string, matlab, exception

I am trying to convert MException into a one-line string which I can then append to a log file, however for some reason I cannot remove the newline characters within the error message.

```
try 
    error("rand Error")
catch err
    a = string(getReport(err, 'extended','hyperlinks', 'off'))
end
```

It seems that the newline char is not '\n' but '↵' I tried deleting it with strrep(a,'↵','') and erase(a,'↵') but neither worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'↵'` is the combined carriage return and line feed character; you can remove it using `strrep(a,"\r\n",'')` or `erase(a,"\r\n")`.